# undefined variable in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function-call

I am newbie to MATLAB .I have written a code to upsample a data.when executed always shrows the particular error(below)

**??? Input argument "n" is undefined.
Error in ==> upsamp at 7
mm=min(n)**

but when i just write the foll. output [n1,y]=upsamp([1,2,3,4,5,6],-1:4,3) command window ,its shows me the correct upsampled data with its figure.

then why the error is popping up? Or i just click on run button,and error is shown in command window.

Please help me out to debug that error:

My code is

```
function[n1,y]=upsamp(n,x,I)

mm=min(n)
mx=max(n)
n1=mm*I:(mx*I+I-1)
x1=x'
x1=[x1,zeros(length(x),I-1)]
x1=x1'
y=(x1(:))'

subplot(2,1,1)
stem(n,x)
title('original sequence ')
xlabel('Range')
ylabel('sequence')

subplot(2,1,2)
stem(n1,y)
title(' unsampling')
xlabel('Range')
ylabel('sequence')

end
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted, if you want to run a function that takes input arguments, you have to call it manually from the command prompt with any required arguments.

Otherwise, if you like to use the *Run button (F5)*  from the editor, consider creating a [**run configuration**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_env/brqxeeu-131.html#brqxeeu-136) (they can be used in [smart](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2008/06/23/profiling-using-run-configurations/) [ways](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2009/12/14/using-run-configurations-for-debugging/))

[image: run_configuration]

Answer (score 1):

The "run" button is only for scripts (i.e. just a plain list of statements without "function" at the top). This is a function, so it should only get called from the matlab command line like you described.

Answer (score 0):

The run button calls your function with no arguments.

Since arguments to your function are non-optional, you get an error.

Either call your function from the interactive Command Window, or write a short script that provides appropriate arguments, and use the Run button with that script.  You can still single-step into your function.